# I have Windows 10 build 11082 and noticed it's in a new release branch, "rs1_release" What's "rs1_release"?

Tags: windows-10

This is the first time I've seen "rs1_release" listed in the Registry under the "BuildLab" and "BuildLabEx" keys and wondering what is "rs1_release", does anyone know?

Here's my BuildLab and BuildLabEx information:

BuildLab: 11082.rs1_release.151210-2021
BuildLabEx: 11082.1000.amd64fre.rs1_release.151210-2021

Answer (score 4):

The "RS" stands for "Redstone" which is the development branch Microsoft is now working from (now that Threshold 2 has been released).

More info:

- [Windows 10: Codename Redstone (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10#Codename_.22Redstone.22)
- [Redstone development branch “rs1_release” showing up for some Windows Insiders](http://www.winbeta.org/news/redstone-development-branch-rs1_release-showing-up-for-some-windows-insiders)
- [What's the Difference Between rs1_release and th2_release?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_update/whats-the-difference-between-rs1release-and/c4268333-dac9-41f5-9d05-be55936bd4ea)